# Set padding into canvas container with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I try to insert an SVG element into a canvas. I would like to add padding for math equations inside the canvas.

You can see the first result without padding on [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/932d8q4w/8/)

Now, if I take a positive value for padding, the dimensions (width and length) are increasing. For example, with a padding equal to `20px`, I get the following result : [link for `padding: 20px`](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/932d8q4w/7/).

Finally, If I take a larger value (`padding: 60px`), I get this result :

[link for `padding: 60px`](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/932d8q4w/6/)

You can notice for each of these 3 cases that I put "`box-sizing: border-box;`" for "`<canvas width="400px" height="400px" id="textbox"></canvas>`"

```
#textbox {
position: absolute;
padding: 60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #333333;
border: 2px solid #428bca;
z-index: 100;
}
```

I would like to set padding for math equations without changing the size of canvas : I thought that `box-sizing: border-box;` could allow me to get this result.

Anyone could see where the problem comes from ?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1 :**

The solution given by AlexK doesn't precisely solve my issue. you can see [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/cjafru1m/2) where I have added the math equations, you will notice that equations are centered vertically and horizontally inside green square but what I would like to get is to put the block of equations (I mean from the first line of block equations) at the top left corner of green square.

Comment: You know you can modify the parameters passed in drawImage ? http://jsfiddle.net/cjafru1m/8/ Also, as I already told you on your previous question, you would be better just to style the container with CSS, or even do everything with the canvas API : http://jsfiddle.net/cjafru1m/11/ And finally, to avoid the problems while drawing your svg, fix its bounding box with the `viewBox` attribute so that there is no top or bottom margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `width` and `height` **CSS** properties, as well as their HTML attribute counterparts. Note that you'll want to keep the same aspect ratio, or the image will appear distorted.

**Update:** draw the image in its original aspect ratio too, or it will be stretched!

```js
var textCanvas = document.getElementById('textbox');
var contextTextBox = textCanvas.getContext('2d');

contextTextBox.fillStyle = "green";
contextTextBox.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  contextTextBox.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 378, 150);
};
img.src = "http://example.com/test_last/formulaWhite.svg";
```

```css
#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid #428bca;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
#containerCanvas {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerCanvas">
  <canvas width="400" height="400" id="textbox"></canvas>
</div>
```

The **HTML** `height` and `width` properties control the resolution of your drawing space - they allow you to fit more or less content in the drawing area. The **CSS** dimensions will scale the canvas to occupy a certain amount of space on-screen.

Here's an example with more "drawing area", yet takes up the same 400x400 pixels on-screen.

```js
var textCanvas = document.getElementById('textbox');
var contextTextBox = textCanvas.getContext('2d');

contextTextBox.fillStyle = "green";
contextTextBox.fillRect(0, 0, 756, 756);

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  contextTextBox.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 378, 150);
  contextTextBox.drawImage(img, 378, 0, 378, 150);
  contextTextBox.drawImage(img, 0, 150, 378, 150);
  contextTextBox.drawImage(img, 378, 150, 378, 150);
};
img.src = "http://example.com/test_last/formulaWhite.svg";
```

```css
#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid #428bca;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 60px;
}

#containerCanvas {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerCanvas">
  <canvas width="756" height="756" id="textbox"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that I had to add again into CSS the width and height of values set into <canvas width="400" height="400" id="textbox"> tag. A last comment : why the padding of top (above the equations) is larger than left padding ? and how to fix it in order to have the same padding for both ? regards

Comment: @youpilat13 the padding is the same on all sides - you can verify that [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/cjafru1m/). However, you are drawing the image as 300x300, which is not the original aspect ratio, so the image appears distorted. You can see how it looks with the correct aspect ratio [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/tcn1y6yL/). Hope my answer solves your issues!

Comment: AlexK: The solution given by AlexK doesn't precisely solve my issue. you can see http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/cjafru1m/2 where I have added the math equations, you will notice that equations are centered vertically and horizontally inside green square but what I would like to get is to put the block of equations (I mean from the first line of block equations) at the top left corner of green square.

Comment: @youpilat13, you are drawing the image at the wrong aspect ratio, so it is getting stretched. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to test it

Comment: This seems to be good. Just a last question : how did you find the values 378 for width and 150 for height (for dimension of equations block) ? It has been taken randomly or you computed them from SVG file ? thanks

Comment: @youpilat13, I inspected the SVG in the browser to get the dimensions.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't find these values into the SVG, maybe you have done a small computation with "width="26.383ex" height="10.509ex" style="vertical-align: -4.366ex;" viewBox="0 -2513.6 11359.3 4524.8" values (header of SVG) ?